# different programming language and calling convention

Tags: c++, python, c, calling-convention

According to the wiki:

> Different programming languages use different calling conventions, and
>   so can different platforms (CPU architecture + operating system). This
>   can sometimes cause problems when combining modules written in
>   multiple languages

So am I supposed to be careful when I call C/C++ functions (exported from .so/.dll) in Python?
If yes, what should I be careful of?

Comment: What utility are you using to call C++ functions from Python?

Comment: @EthanSteinberg, ctypes maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calling convention is not an issue when calling C from python because the python interpreter itself is written in C, and thus uses the same calling convention as the C code.

It becomes an issue when combining code written in different compiled languages, for example C and Ada.

Usually C is the system programming language, and thus the standard. This means that a compiler for any language will generally have special support to inter-operate with C. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Interfacing-to-C.html) for an example of interoperability between C and Ada. If there is no special support wrappers must be written at the assembly level.

If you need to call C++/Ada from python you'll have to follow a two steps process. The first step is to write a C wrapper around the C++/Ada functions. The second step is to call the C wrapper from python.

Take for example the following C++ class.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo ();
  int bar ();
  ...
};
```

If you want to make it available to python, you first need to wrap it in C:

```
extern "C" {
typedef void *FooPtr;
FooPtr foo_new () { return (FooPtr)new Foo(); }
int foo_bar (FooPtr foo) { return ((Foo*)foo)->bar(); }
...
}
```

Then you can call that from python. (Note, in real life there are tools to automate this, like [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/libs/python/doc/)).

Note that there are two aspects of writing a wrapper: converting between calling conventions and converting between type representations. The later part is usually the most difficult because as soon as you go beyond basic types languages tend to have very different representations of equivalent types.

Comment: So, what should be taken care of and how, if I call C from Ada?

Answer (score 5):

Calling between Python and C is a solved problem, so you generally won't have to worry about anything -- not least because Python is written in C.

The problem described there is more an issue when multiple languages on a platform are all developed independently, individually bootstrapped from assembler. For example, there used to famously be problems calling between C and FORTRAN, and between C and Pascal, at a time when all three of those languages coexisted as rough equals. The old Mac Toolbox was written mostly in assembler using Pascal calling conventions, and early application developers used Borland Pascal. But then C compilers like Symatec's THINK C appeared, and those programmers had to specifically worry about how to translate argument types and string conventions (Pascal strings carry a length byte at the beginning, and of course C strings have a 0 at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ have different calling conventions. C doesn't support calling C++ functions but C++ support calling C functions and supports the implementation of C functions in C++. That is, you can declare functions as `extern "C"` in C++. I don't know how the python bindings are calling C++ but you should be careful to call C and C++ functions with their respective calling conventions. Generally, C calling conventions are used when calling between different languages. This may mean that you might need to write a wrapper function using C style conventions for C++ style functions.

Comment: What you are referring to is the name mangling used for linking, not the calling convention.

Comment: No, that is **not** what I'm referring to! Function call conventions can be different between C and C++. Please see 7.5 [dcl.link] for information on what I'm talking of.

Comment: Yes, but that is confusing, and the typical reason you wrap a C++ call in C is because of the name mangling, not because of the calling convention. With some compilers you can declare the calling convention of the function, and it will compile to that convention. This is typically used for compatibility with shared libraries compiled with a different calling convention than standard C.

Comment: I don't see any confusion: the different name mangling to subsumed by the different calling conventions. It is worth noting, however, that even if match the mangled system exactly, you won't always be happy calling the function if it doesn't also match the exact details on how the function is to be called.

Comment: After doing more research both C and C++ use the same calling convention: cdecl. The reason you wrap a C++ call in a C wrapper is because of name mangling, and no other reason. See: http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/a/conventions_2.htm

Comment: You need to research more: there are platform where the C and C++ calling conventions are different. The `cdecl` stuff is Windows specific. The C++ standard and its support for different language calling conventions is cross-platform. It is correct that on most platforms the main difference is the name mangling. On other platforms it also affects how arguments are passed and values are returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7434/discussion-between-grieve-and-dietmar-kuhl)

Answer (score 0):

The calling conventions refers to how functions calls are generated in the resulting assembly. One convention is for the caller to be responsible for creating and cleaning up the stack space for the local variables. The other convention is for the called function to create and clean up the stack space for the local variables. It doesn't matter which one you use, but obviously they have to match or the stack will get corrupted.

You can see more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention